# Laravel SQL General error: 4015 Window function is allowed only in SELECT list and ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to get the next row and previous row id in Laravel but it wont let me do it without getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4015 Window function is allowed only
> in SELECT list and ORDER BY clause (SQL: SELECT OrderID, EmployeeID,
> LEAD(OrderID,1) OVER ( ORDER BY OrderID ) nextID, lag(OrderID,1) OVER
> ( ORDER BY OrderID ) previous FROM orders group BY OrderID,
> EmployeeID, nextID, previous )

This is the code am working on

```
$order = DB::select(DB::raw(" 
    SELECT
        OrderID, 
        EmployeeID,
        LEAD(OrderID,1) OVER (
            ORDER BY OrderID
        ) nextID,
        lag(OrderID,1) OVER (
            ORDER BY OrderID
        ) previous
        
    FROM 
        orders

    group BY
        OrderID,
        EmployeeID,
        nextID,
        previous
    "))->orderby('OrderID', 'EmployeeID', 'nextID', 'previous')->get();
```

Comment: have you tried to execute your query without GROUP BY ?

Comment: yes then it just says: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Comment: it looks very suspicious. Can you execute this query SELECT
        OrderID, 
        EmployeeID,
        LEAD(OrderID,1) OVER (
            ORDER BY OrderID
        ) nextID,
        lag(OrderID,1) OVER (
            ORDER BY OrderID
        ) previous
        
    FROM 
        orders     in any db-client. It looks correct one

Comment: yes i can execute it via phpmyadmin without errors (northwind database)

Comment: workbench doesn't show any error without the group, but your query doesn't make any sense, the should be a partition for employeeid or at least an order by in the window function

Comment: I know laravel is not really letting me do LEAD and LAG because its windowed so the code got messy

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is will help someone.

SQL Query

```sql
select *, lead(start_loc,1) over(PARTITION BY dri_id order by start_time asc) as next_start_ride from `drivers` group by `dri_id`
```

Laravel Query Builder

```php
$data = DB::table('drivers')->select(
            '*', 
            DB::raw('lead(start_loc,1) over(PARTITION BY dri_id order by start_time asc) as next_start_ride')
        )->get();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$order = DB::table('orders')
    ->select(
        'OrderID', 
        'EmployeeID',
        DB::raw('LEAD(OrderID,1) OVER (ORDER BY OrderID) as nextID'),
        DB::raw('LAG(OrderID,1) OVER (ORDER BY OrderID) as previous')
    )
    ->groupBy('OrderID', 'EmployeeID', 'nextID', 'previous')
    ->orderBy('OrderID', 'EmployeeID', 'nextID', 'previous')
    ->get();
```